# Calling `every` and `some` methods of an empty array returns weird results

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript why does the line `[].every(Boolean)` return `true`? And `[].some(Boolean)` returns `false`?

If there are no elements in the array, then they are kind of undefined (undeclared), thus falsy. According to this, snippets with arrays `[null]` or `[undefined]`, return `false` exactly as predicted.
But any empty array should not call the callback `Boolean` at the first place, and return something like `undefined` or `null`, thus `false` again.

What I've missed?

It looks like, what JS interpreter really does is that `Boolean([])` (in the first situation). And that of course returns `true`. Maybe that is correct?

Comment: Not a technical answer, but you may be interested in the mathematical notion of [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"every" returns true if every element of an array passes a test. If there are no items in the array, "every" element in the array passes the test.

"some" returns true if at least one element of an array passes a test. If the array is empty, none of the elements pass the test and it returns false.

> It looks like, what JS interpreter really does is that Boolean([]) (in the first situation). And that of course returns true. Maybe that is correct?

With an empty array, neither `every` nor `some` call the callback at all because there is nothing to test. You can check this with:

```
[].every(() => console.log("this never prints"));
[].some(() => console.log("this never prints"));
```